# URL_GET and TVCHANNEL_IMAGE: No longer returning matches

Tags: gracenote

I am using Gracenote video services for the programming guide in my application.  Within the guide, I display channel logos along with the channel name and number.  In the past, I have retrieved channel logo URLs by using the URL_GET API query with the mode set to TVCHANNEL_IMAGE. Within the body of the query, I would include the Gracenote IDs for a set of channels (found in a TVCHANNEL_LOOKUP response).  Below is an example query.

```
<QUERIES>
<AUTH>
<CLIENT>XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</CLIENT>
<USER>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</USER>
</AUTH>
<QUERY CMD="URL_GET">
<MODE>TVCHANNEL_IMAGE</MODE>
<GN_ID>251535939-B76CB793D827E8BE713DAEB9675ADED4</GN_ID>
<GN_ID>251539612-E293EAF3F3164B292AD102532BCB9AF9</GN_ID>
</QUERY>
</QUERIES>
```

The response to the query would return URLs that I could then download the logos from.  This was working fine up until one week ago.  Now, the response returns with no match.

```
<RESPONSES>
 <RESPONSE STATUS="NO_MATCH">
 </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSES>
```

Has the API for retrieving channel logos changed?  If so, how and what is the new method for getting channel logos?  Ideally, I would like to continue downloading logos on demand through an API similar to URL_GET.

Comment: Your query appears to be well-formed according to the Gracenote docs: https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/eyeq-webapi-ref.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Are you still able to reproduce this?  I get a valid response back using your query example

```
<RESPONSES>
<RESPONSE STATUS="OK">
    <TVCHANNEL>
        <GN_ID>251535939-B76CB793D827E8BE713DAEB9675ADED4</GN_ID>
        <URL TYPE="IMAGE" SIZE="110" WIDTH="67" HEIGHT="50">http://akamai-b.cdn.cddbp.net/cds/2.0/image/E9F4/7FE7/D525/9746_110.png</URL>
    </TVCHANNEL>
    <TVCHANNEL>
        <GN_ID>251539612-E293EAF3F3164B292AD102532BCB9AF9</GN_ID>
        <URL TYPE="IMAGE" SIZE="110" WIDTH="67" HEIGHT="50">http://akamai-b.cdn.cddbp.net/cds/2.0/image/F1D1/F628/A3FE/79E0_110.png</URL>
    </TVCHANNEL>
</RESPONSE>
</RESPONSES>
```